# Qt - executable is crashing while starting

Tags: qt, dll, crash

i have created my Qt program and I copied the dll's according to the error messages while starting my program from the qt/bin ordner to the direction of the program.

Now the program is crashing with following error:

> Problemsignatur:   Problemereignisname:   APPCRASH   Anwendungsname:  XXX
>   Anwendungsversion:    0.0.0.0   Anwendungszeitstempel:    53ba7c53
>   Fehlermodulname:  ntdll.dll   Fehlermodulversion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   Fehlermodulzeitstempel:   4a5bdb3b   Ausnahmecode:    80000003
>   Ausnahmeoffset:   0001000c   Betriebsystemversion:    6.1.7600.2.0.0.768.3 
>   Gebietsschema-ID: 1031   Zusatzinformation 1: 9492   Zusatzinformation
>   2:    9492440c23a499abdbcf787b7d5054c4   Zusatzinformation 3: c092
>   Zusatzinformation 4:  c0928fd8a73e46bd97c20de675daf856

That are the extensions, i copied to the folder:
http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/unbenannt42od61ns7h.png

What's the problem?

Thank you for help.

Greetings

Comment: Hi, well we don't have enough information to help you. So you're on Windows thanks to the screen, what program do you compile ? Did you succeed to run it before trying to deploy it ? Do you compile in debug or release mode ?

Comment: Are you building and running it on the command line or with an IDE ? What toolchain are you using (Mingw / VC++ / other) ? Have you used [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check all the DLLs are present ?

Comment: I compiled it with the Qt Creator in Release Mode and i copied the dll's in the release folder.
Toolchain? I use the "Qt Creator".

Dependency Walker:
http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/12d95ncl1ji.png

Thank you for help

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to copy _ntdll.dll_, and in the platforms folder do you have _qminimal.dll_ and _qwindows.dll_?

Comment: Yes. Now I have deleted the ntdll.dll and the platforms folder cleared, so there's only qminimal.dll and qwindows.dll.

Comment: And for my setup i needed _libEGL.dll_ too (i used multimedia module, so that might needed that dll, but you can try and see if it works)

Comment: Hmm, the same error again. :/